# While using Offline data sync with Azure Mobile Apps SDK Can I control the order in which the table are synced?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

We are generating the Primary Keys from(GUID) from client side and passing to server.
From some of the articles and blogs we came to know that Azure client sdk pushes the records in random order.
We have created a 2 tables with relations and tested this in offline mode and it works well. So we would like to confirm if the latest client side sdk has done some code fix to send the records in some order.

I wonder why can't they create a queue so that it will push the first in first out manner.

Since we have foriegn key relations in server side we need to push the inserts in an orderly manner, is there any mechanism to make this pushes to server in a specified order?

Comment: If it is useful, please mark it that will help more communities who have the same issue easily to search.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any mechanism to make this pushes to server in a specified order?

We could get the answer from this [book-chapter3/relationships/](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/).

> The former is generally handled for you. If you InsertAsync a tag in offline mode, it will be placed into the operations queue prior to anything that uses it. Since the operations queue is processed in order, the tag will be sent to the backend prior to any record updates that would use it.

**Note:** Prefer handling tables **individually** and handling relationship management on the mobile client **manually.** This causes more code on the mobile client but makes the server much simpler by **avoiding most of the complexity of relationships**.